# Macro output explanation

Tags: c++, c, macros

Can someone explain the output of this program -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 

#define FUDGE(k) k+3.14159
#define PR(a) printf(#a" = %d\t ",(int)(a))
#define PRINT(a) PR(a);putchar('\n')

int main()
{
    int x=2;

    PRINT(x*FUDGE(2));
    printf(\n);
    PR(x*FUDGE(2));

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT -

```
x*2+3.14159 = 7

x*FUDGE(2) = 7
```

Why is `FUDGE(2)` getting printed in second and not in the first statement.

Comment: Check out these two links: [Stringizing Operator(#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x.aspx_) and [Token-Pasting Operator (##)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx).  Of the two, you're far likelier to encounter "##" in the wild...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#` operator is strange. It works before expanding the parameter.

So when calling `PR(x*FUDGE(2))`,  `#` is applied to `x*FUDGE(2)` before `FUDGE` is expanded.
However, in `PRINT(x*FUDGE(2))`, `FUDGE` is expanded before passing it on to `PR`. When `PR` applies `#` to it, it has already been expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first you use `PRINT` which expands the argument when it "calls" `PR`.